# htaccess rewrite for a folder but not if containing additional url parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

Is it possible to redirect if a url hits a certain point and when additional url information is added the redirect ignores it?

Example: 
www.mysite.com/myevent/   (would redirect to www.mysite.com/events/)
BUT
www.mysite.com/myevent/a-random-event-title     (would NOT redirect)

The 'a-random-event-title' would be different each time and so cannot be selected specifically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can tweak your regex for that. Consider this rule using `mod_alias`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/myevent/?$ /events/
```

This will ONLY redirect `/myevent` OR `/myevent/` to `/events` while `/myevent/anything` will remain unaffected (not redirected)

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.